# Pygame draw.rect not working with rect argument

Tags: python, pygame

Trying to make a clone of space invaders. I'm following a guide from here https://kidscancode.org/blog/2016/08/pygame_shmup_part_5/. This is the player sprite

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Player, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('./Assets/PNG/playerShip1_orange.png').convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 40))

        # WIN_SIZE = 500, 500

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIN_SIZE[0] / 2
        self.rect.bottom = WIN_SIZE[1] - 10
        self.speedx = 0

        #   NOT WORKING FOR SOME REASON
        #   self.image.fill(WHITE, self.rect)
        #   pygame.draw.rect(self.image, WHITE, self.rect, 1)
        #   pygame.draw.circle(self.image, WHITE, self.rect.center, 25, 1)
        
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, WHITE, ( (0,0), (50, 40) ), 1)
```

I want to create a rectangular outline around the sprite, which i'm able to do if i use the last line in above code. However, the commented code doesn't work for some reason even though each argument is correct and no compile/runtime error is thrown.

**Relevent Snippets from Main Class**

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        self._win = pygame.display.set_mode(WIN_SIZE, 0, 32)
        self._clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        
        self._all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        
        self._player = Player()
        self._all_sprites.add(self._player)
        
        self._game_over = False

    def run(self):

        while not self._game_over:
            
            self._clock.tick(FPS)

            self._all_sprites.update()
            self._all_sprites.draw(self._win)

            pygame.display.flip()

def main():
    game = Game()
    game.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Complete Source : https://github.com/muneeb-devp/Shmup**

Any sorta help would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Nope, like i said i don't get any errors but the commented code is supposed to create an outline around the sprite. It doesn't work if i pass the self.rect object, however it works fine if i manually pass it a rect like this (0,0, 50, 50). I'm guessing it has something to do with position since (0,0,50,50) is working even though the sprite is located at ( win_width / 2, win_height - 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw the outline on the image, before the position of the rectangle is set:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

pygame.draw.rect(self.image, WHITE, self.rect, 1)
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, WHITE, self.rect.center, 25, 1)

self.rect.centerx = WIN_SIZE[0] // 2
self.rect.bottom = WIN_SIZE[1] - 10
self.speedx = 0
```

The location of the rectangle which is returned by `get_rect()` is (0, 0). This is also the top left position of the outline in the image. Note, you draw the outline on the image not on the display.

Comment: This solved the issue but could you please elaborate why it doesn't work after setting rectangle's position?

Comment: @MuneebMughal I've explained that in the answer. `get_rect()` returns a rectangle (0, 0, width, height). When you do `self.rect.center = (x, y)` then the rectangle is (x, y, width, height) and this rectangle is not on the image. You draw on the image, not on the display. The image object itself (`self.image`) has no location, it drawn at a position on the display but the outline has to be in the image.